# Basic 'For Loop' Compile Error

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Scanner tool is imported.
public class Sales   
{
    public static void main (String[] args) // Main.
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);   // Scanner object is instantiated.

        String[] name = new String[5]; // First array for names is created.
        double[] sales = new double[5]; // Second array for sales is created.

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {    // For loop to ask each question 5 times.
            System.out.println ("What is the name of the person?");
            name[i] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("How much did he/she sell?");
             sales[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {    // loop to print the salesperson and amount of sales.
           System.out.println (name[j] + " sold " + sales[j]);aa
        }


        int sum = 0;   // The sum is calculated using a for loop.
        for (double k : sales){
            sum+=k;
        }

        double avg = sum / 5;  // The average is calculated.
        System.out.println ("The average sales is: " + avg);

        if (sales[i] >= avg){  // whether or not the person sold greater than average.
            System.out.println (name[i] + " sold more than the average sales.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Compile Error:

```
Sales.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
         if (sales[i] >= avg){  // Indicates whether or not the person sold greater than average.
                   ^   symbol:   variable i   location: class Sales Sales.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
         System.out.println (name[i] + " sold more than the average sales.");
                                  ^   symbol:   variable i   location: class Sales 2 errors
```

I have tried changing the 'i' to 'j'.... but that did not work either. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `System.out.println (name[j] + " sold " + sales[j]);aa` <- What is that?

Comment: You should format this code correctly, it's a bit tough to read. Also, I think you ended the for loop containing `i` so at the line `sales[i] <= avg` your `i` variable is no longer in scope.

Comment: The same goes for your `j` variable. I see you said that you tried that, but it has the same problem as `i`, it is out of scope at the point you are using it.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I'll try playing around with it. Thx

Comment: I have provided a possible solution for you below. That will help you see what I am describing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did in fact fix the issue. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that you are using a for loop which declares an int `i` in the beginning of your code. However, when this for loop is done, that int `i` is now gone.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println ("What is the name of the person?");
} // <-- After this your int i is gone
```

That int, because it is declared inside the for loop, only lasts for the lifetime of that loop. Later on in your code you are trying to use that same int `i` which no longer exists. This is the same exact reason why changing it to a `j` didn't work. The loop in which you declared your int `j` has also completed by the time you get to your problem area.

Try adding another for loop at the problem area like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (sales[i] >= avg){  // whether or not the person sold greater than average.
        System.out.println (name[i] + " sold more than the average sales.");
    }
}
```

This will give you the variable `i` which is in scope and can be used in the way you are trying.

Also, as a side note, you may want to change your for loops to use `sales.size` instead of an explicit number. This will make it easier for you if you change the size of the array later on.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two foreign characters at the end of this line of code that need to be deleted.

```
System.out.println (name[j] + " sold " + sales[j]);aa
```

It's also complaining about `i` because there isn't a variable with that name in scope at that particular line. The `i` that you previously declared only exists for the duration of your first for loop.

An easy fix for this would be to wrap that if-statement in another loop. You probably need one there anyway since you're trying to find out who sold more than the average:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++){
    if (sales[i] >= avg){  // whether or not the person sold greater than average.
        System.out.println (name[i] + " sold more than the average sales.");
    }
}
```

Edit: This is unrelated to your question but your prompt for the person's name will be skipped on subsequent runs of your loop. You might want to add another `scan.nextLine()` after your call to `nextDouble()` to consume the trailing new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it cannot find it because you're referencing the variable "i" outside the for loop. The variable defined by for (int i=0;...) is only visible to the for loop and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println (name[j] + " sold " + sales[j]);aa` try removing the aa from the code.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println (name[j] + " sold " + sales[j]);aa`

I think that `aa` needs to be deleted

Comment: I realized that before posting this... and after removing it, got a different symbol error. (the one in my post). Sorry for the confusion... any ideas about the error? thx